pinescript labels are deleted when tradingview is updated
I'm trying to output my indicator labels on my chart under certain conditions. This works even if my script runs from the market start. Unfortunately, the labels are deleted again after a tradingview chart update. Var values ​​are also deleted again in a table on the chart and are no longer displayed. It seems that this is just a display error that the script runs without errors. The script runs with real-time candles. So how can I safely output labels under certain conditions without them being deleted again by the character update and also displayed in real time in the past and current candles?
